# Controller must wait until Directive is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently writing a small set of AngularJS controls, and I'm encountering an issue here.
The control which I'm creating is a button (let's start simple).

The directive looks like this:

```
officeButton.directive('officeButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            isDefault: '@',
            isDisabled: '@',
            control: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="button-wrapper" data-ng-click="onClick()">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="button normal-button">' +
                      '<span>{{label}}</span>' +
                    '</a>' +
                  '</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            // Controller code removed for clarity.
        }],

        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) { 
            // Link code removed for clarity.
        }
    }
});
```

I've removed some code because it will make my question very hard to understand and I don't believe it's needed here.

Inside my `controller` of my directive, I'm writing an API and that being done by executing the following code:

```
controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Allows an API on the directive.
    $scope.api = $scope.control || {};

    $scope.api.changeLabel = function(label) 
        $scope.label = label;
    }
}]
```

So, on my directive, I do have an isolated scope to which I can pass a `control` property. Through this property, I'll have access to the method `changeLabel`.

My control can be rendered by using the following directive in the HTML website:

```
<office-button control="buttonController"></office-button>
```

The controller on my application will looks like:

```
officeWebControlsApplication.controller('OfficeWebControlsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.buttonController = {};
}]);
```

I can execute my `changeLabel` method right now by calling the following method in my `scope`

```
$scope.buttonController.changeLabel('Demo');
```

However, this doesn't work since at this point `changeLabel` is not defined. The button must first be completely rendered.

Any idea on how to resolve this particular issue?

**Edit: Plunker Added**

I've added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWKugTwLK2GwVZJ3XK7M?p=info) to provide more information.
When the `changeLabel` method is called within the `onClick` event, then everything is working, but if I call it outside, it isn't working anymore. This is because the $scope.api.changeLabel is not defined at the moment of execution (button is not rendered yet). So I basically have to wait in my application's controller until the button is fully rendered.

Kind regards

Comment: Please provide plunker

Comment: There are a few questions that popped up immediately in my mind. Can you tell be the use of 2 different controllers, one in the directive and other OfficeWebControlsController? What are you trying to achieve with control attribute of your directive? If you have defined changeLabel in directive controller, how would you call it within other scope?

Comment: @manasisakhare That's working through the API call, but I'll create a plunker right away giving more information.

Comment: @ArepalliPraveenkumar I've added a plunker to demonstrate the problem. You mind looking again?

Comment: You could try to use `$timeout` instead. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jCQRIN3TCh6mHdovGuVL?p=preview)

Comment: You're wrapping the 'onClick' in a timeout function, which isn't what I wanted. I don't want to respond to the onclick method. Instead just execute changeLabel on page load.